# How do I customize building the monero full node with flags, parameters, or configuration files?

Tags: build, compile

I only want to use `monero-wallet-cli` on the same machine as `monerod`.
I build my full node on Debian Desktop by running:

```
  git clone --recursive https://github.com/monero-project/monero
  cd "monero"
  git checkout master
  make -Wno-dev
```

**1.** Do I need to build `monero-blockchain-ancestry`        `monero-blockchain-prune-known-spent-data`
`monero-blockchain-depth`             `monero-blockchain-stats`
`monero-blockchain-export` `monero-blockchain-usage`
`monero-blockchain-import` `monero-gen-ssl-cert`
`monero-blockchain-mark-spent-outputs`  `monero-gen-trusted-multisig`
`monero-blockchain-prune`             `monero-wallet-rpc`
for that purpose?

**2.** Are there flags and parameters that I could pass to in order to save on CPU and storage by not building any of the binaries listed above? Which of the binaries above is a GUI wallet (I would rather delete it)?

**3.** Where can I read more on each of the binary listed above?

Answer (score 2):

1. Building with the above command builds all these programs. I'm not sure how to only build `monerod`.
2. The Monero GUI wallet is not available the `monero` repo. You need to build the GUI from the different repo https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui
3. You can read about many of these programs on https://getmonero.dev/docs/interacting/overview.html